# Handle wordrap deliminator in CLOB fields

Tags: regex, oracle

I have this request below that does exactly what I want but  it does it only if the fields Author_ID and Author_Name are VARCHAR and values within them are separated by stars like in this table:

```
ID_BOOK | ID_AUTHOR |       NAME AUTHOR       |
-----------------------------------------------
001     |01         | AuthorU                 | 
-----------------------------------------------
002     |02*03*04   | AuthorX*AuthorY*AuthorZ |
-----------------------------------------------
```

The request will give me this result:

```
ID_BOOK | ID_AUTHOR |       NAME AUTHOR       |
-----------------------------------------------
001     |01         | AuthorU                 |
-----------------------------------------------
002     |02         | AuthorX                 |
-----------------------------------------------
002     |03         | AuthorY                 |
-----------------------------------------------
002     |04         | AuthorZ                 |
-----------------------------------------------
```

BUT in real life these two fields are CLOB and there is no star deliminator, there i a wordrap deliminator, so data looks like that in real life:

```
ID_BOOK | ID_AUTHOR |       NAME AUTHOR       |
-----------------------------------------------
001     |01         | AuthorU                 | 
-----------------------------------------------
002     |02*03*04   | AuthorXAuthorYAuthorZ   |
```

I'm trying to have the same result that i got it with the Varchar fields and the star deliminator because with CLOB I can't use REGEXP_SUBSTR and I don't know how to handle the wordrap deliminator. Could you please help me with some hints. Many thanks.

```
SELECT
 ID_Book,
 REGEXP_SUBSTR(ID_Author, '[^*]+', 1, Counter) AS AuthID,
 REGEXP_SUBSTR(Name_Author, '[^*]+', 1, Counter) AS AuthName
FROM Books
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT LEVEL Counter
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (      
      SELECT MAX(REGEXP_COUNT(ID_Author, '[^*]+'))
      FROM Books))
WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(Name_Author, '[^*]+', 1, Counter) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Comment: What character is used as `wordrap deliminator`?

Comment: Hi Egor, when I open SqlDeveloper and take a look to the data, it displays them concatenated, but when I double click to change the value of the field it shows me every value on a line, that's why i said to myself that it uses a wordrap as a deliminator but unfortunately i can't say how..

Answer (score 0):

You could convert `clob` to `varchar2` using `to_char` function.

---

**EDIT :**
If `Name_Author` is a CLOB, try

```
  to_char(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Name_Author, '[^'||chr(10)||chr(13)||']+', 1, Counter))
```

or

```
  to_char(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Name_Author, '^.*?$', 1, Counter, 'm'))
```

The latter expression is shorter, but it does not strip out `chr(13)` symbols.

Comment: Thank you Egor, but REGEXP_SUBSTR doesn't work correctly with Oracle 9.i I think :( Even REGEXP_COUNT doesn't work with Oracle 9.i but i found a workaround for it, now i'm looking for a workaround for REGEXP_SUBSTR but I don't want tou use the classic SUBSTR function because it works with start position and length. Take a look to this  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c0f19/10 , Thank you anyway :)

Comment: @Walloud - On Oracle 9 you should use `substr` and `instr` instead of `REGEXP_SUBSTR`; `length` and `replace` instead of `REGEXP_COUNT`.  Lines are separated by `chr(10)` char.

Comment: Thank you Egor, I will dig into it :)